# Where can I edit a calendar's working time in Microsoft Project 2010?

Tags: microsoft-project

In the older versions of Microsoft Project, I could use the wizard to easily find and edit the project calendars. I did this often to add holidays and so on.

Now I have to set a different working time for an intern in my project, but I'm unable to. Project 2010 lets me create exceptions somewhat quickly, but I can't find the button to edit the calendar and change the working time to 6 hours/day for this person.

In addition, where can I delete a calendar that I created?

Comment: @Daniel: I was uncertain if I should post it here or there, but since I use project to organize a team of developers, I thought it would fit here. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but it certainly worked for setting up non/working times, given that the MS help was absolutely useless. However I'm not too sure how you would go about having one person work on a different calendar.

1. Go to the *Project* tab in the ribbon.
2. Click the ***Change Working Time*** button in the *Properties* group.
3. Click **Create New Calendar**
4. Make a copy of *"24 Hours"*
5. Add an exception (table at bottom)
6. Call it anything and click **Details**
7. Choose *Working times* and specify the required working times
8. Recurrence to *Daily*
9. Set the start and end dates well outside project scope
10. Click ***Project*** Information in the *Project* tab of the ribbon
11. Change the Calendar to your new calendar

Answer (score 2):

To manage the calendars in Project 2010, follow these steps once your project is open:

1. Click on "File" (in the Ribon), then "Info".
2. Click on the button "Organizer". A new window will pop up.
3. Click on the tab "Calendars".
4. Delete, rename and move calendars for your project, and globally (Global.mpt).

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a resource and you want to edit their working time independently of any of your case calendars, the best thing to do is this:

1. Go to the Resource Sheet view.
2. Double-click on the resource (your Intern) that you want to change.
3. On the dialog box, go to the General tab.
4. Click the Change Working Time... button

You can now edit your Intern's working hours without affecting any other calendars.

You can see a bit more info on creating detailed custom calendars here:

> http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s141/using_vba_to_create_calendars_in_microsoft_project.htm

And a bit about organising your calendars after you've created them here:

> http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s152/using_the_organizer_in_microsoft_project.htm